# Android - Opencv increase FPS

Tags: java, android, performance, opencv

So I've been trying to increase the FPS with OpenCv JavaCameraView with 1280x960 as resolution. I've been trying to find a solution to this but with no luck.
I am only getting 3 FPS when trying to do face-eye detection.
I am using JNI to compile native c++ code for OpenCV with haarcascade. Is there any way to increase this? or is OpenCV just not suited for this task?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Three rounds of eye detection per second isn't so bad. You probably can achieve more with the [Google face detection SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces), but this performance may come with some compromizes with regards to OpenCV algorithms. Note that there exist other, commercial libraries with their own advantages and drawbacks.

On the other hand, it's too bad if you have a live preview that refreshes at 3 FPS.

The trick is to separate the live preview from CV. Sometimes, it comes at cost of missed sychnronization between the picture and detection (that's why this approach is not recommended for Augmented Reality).

Comment: I believe it should be possible, I just believe I have to do something similiar with; stackoverflow.com/questions/15799487/… (But im not sure tho..) These people has actually got it to work with OpenCV, they aren't using NDK but it shouldn't really matter. But THe code project is too big and I can't really seem to understand what part they have done to make sure they have a smooth FPS. github.com/cmauri/eva_facial_mouse

But I believe somehat of a que system which checks for when an image has been detected and when a new one is incomming (async) should improve the performance?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666353/parallel-processing-with-camera2-api-android-and-opencvcamera2 ?

Comment: Note that the 'EVA mouse' does not use live video stream, so they can use minimum video resolution.

Comment: Just found out that the issue might be completlety elsewhere, When running just the JavaCameraCiew from OpenCV I only have MAX 7 fps without any interactions with JNI... which is really weird....
So I believe I need to fix this issue first.
I am using OpenCV 3.4.2...